# Running .app file on iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

So I built my project and I have a .app file from my BUILD location. How can I run this on my simulator without using Xcode ?

I dont not wish to grab the .app file from iPhone Simulator files and pass it to another person. What I require is that, as soon as my .app file is built, I wish to use it to run in the iPhone simulator.

Any tricks ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is, put the .app file in the Users/Library/iPhoneSimulator.. directory and place it similar to the other apps present there.

Close and open the simulator again, and you will be able to see the app on the springboard.

Comment: The correct path is /Users/<user folder>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<simulator version>/Applications/. From there, you will have to use a folder name with a GUID and what not so I would recommend that you just copy/paste another application folder (the GUID folder of another app) and replace the .app file in it. This may be required, not sure: the other folders should be empty. Something to try in case it doesn't work by just replacing the .app file.

Answer (score 3):

The excellent tool [ios-sim](https://github.com/Fingertips/ios-sim) does exactly what you want.